# Is it possible to get the raw request of HttpExchange?

Tags: java, http, httpserver

How can I get the raw request from `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange`?

I'm using `HttpServer` to make a proxy, so I want to get the raw http request and send it to the original host.

Answer (score 0):

The `HttpExchange` API does not support this.  You are (of course) free to create your own class that extends `HttpExchange` and implements its methods however you want.  (The class is really just a set of abstract methods.)

The only other possibility would be to look at some existing implementation of `HttpExchange` in the Sun/Oracle codebase.

- My intuition of how `HttpExchange` would be implemented efficiently is that a generic implementation wouldn't capture the raw request message.
- Even if it did, you would have to "poke around" with the internals of a class that your code shouldn't be using directly.  This is a bad idea for obvious reasons.